# трапециевидный блок с img

Tags: html, css

Кто подскажет идею для реализации такой секции?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант это clip-path

https://jsfiddle.net/tt0nctpt/

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 30% 100%);
```

Comment: Так делал, но для IE не подходит :(

Comment: если под ie9+, то надо со стилями "поиграться", в итоге как то так:

https://jsfiddle.net/tt0nctpt/5/